# Hibernate : Difference between Map and Result Transformer

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I was exploring the way to return map from Hibernate.

I came to know i can do it by two ways

First one was : ***using map***

```
String HQL_QUERY =
                "select new map(hp.col1 , hp.col2) from HP hp where hp.col1 in (:Ids)";
            test =
                getSession().createQuery(HQL_QUERY).setParameterList("Ids", ids).list();
```

Otherone is using  ***setResultTransformer***

```
String HQL_QUERY =
            "select hp.col1 , hp.col2 from HP hp where hp.col1 in (:Ids)";
        test =
            getSession().createQuery(HQL_QUERY).setParameter("Ids", ids)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

In both ways i am getting same result .... no issues.

But i wanna ask if there is any advantage of using one over other.

For example if you are using map you have to write less code , but might be possible that result transformer is more efficient(not sure).

I tried to find it on google but didn't find much.

Please help

Comment: There is no information about efficiency. Both are applicable i guess.

Comment: not efficiency , but might be there are some other differences

Answer (score 0):

They are just two ways of expressing the same thing.

Here is a confirmation from hibernate sources : in `QueryLoader.java` which is the class parsing hql queries :

```
    selectNewTransformer = HolderInstantiator.createSelectNewTransformer(
            selectClause.getConstructor(),
            selectClause.isMap(),
            selectClause.isList());
```

Here the `selectClause.isMap()` will be `true` (if you want to confirm that, have a look at `ConstructorNode.java`)

And then in `HolderInstantiator.java` :

```
public static ResultTransformer createSelectNewTransformer(Constructor constructor, boolean returnMaps, boolean returnLists) {
    if ( constructor != null ) {
        return new AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer(constructor);
    }
    else if ( returnMaps ) {
        return Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP;            
    }
    else if ( returnLists ) {
        return Transformers.TO_LIST;
    }       
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So i guess the `map()` inside the hql select clause being more readable and more concise make it the best choice. Apart from that, exactly the same thing will happen behind the scene.